# php catch simple exception and pdo exceptions both in catch

Tags: php, exception, pdo

```
try {
    $sql = "UPDATE table bla bla bla";
    $bind_param_arr = array();
    $stmt = $conn_p->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($bind_param_arr);
    createLog(200);
    echo (json_encode(array('status' => 200, 'data' => 'Updated Successfully'));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    createLog(500);
    echo (json_encode(array('status' => 500, 'data' => 'There is some error'));
}


function createLog($status)
{
    $log_file = "log.txt";

    $openfile = fopen($log_file, "a");
    if ( ! $openfile) {
        throw new Exception("unable to create log file");
    }
    $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s a");
    fwrite($openfile, $datetime);
    fwrite($openfile, 'Bla bla bla');

    fwrite($openfile, "\n");
    fclose($openfile);
}
```

It's not catching simple exception since i am using instance of PDOException class in catch block. Can i use instance of Exception class instead of PDOException **(then its working)**. 
What is right way ?

Comment: Add another `} catch (Exception $e) {` ?

Comment: You can have multiple `catch` blocks. But you probably should not use `Exception` as that is too general. Instead, define your own that extends `Exception` and throw (and catch...) that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch only **PDOException** and hadle it in a certain way better use **PDOException**.

Sample

```
catch(PDOException $e) {
    handler1($e);
} catch(Exception $e){
    handler2($e);
}
```

If it's not important for you what exception you catch and you handle diffrenet types of exceptions equally then use **Exception**

```
} catch(Exception $e){
    handler($e);
}
```

**Update**

To not handle exception, you can leave handler empty, you should be sure it does not affect anything

Sample:

```
} catch(Exception $e){ 
}
```

Comment: I have another question ? Suppose in the above sample code of mine, if updation is successful but there is an error during creating log file then what should i do. Should i roll back the transaction using commit and rollback features of pdo ?

Comment: @KuldeepThakur depends on your application, if the exception does not affect anything,  you can to not handle it

Answer (score 1):

Use general **Exception** class to catch exception and then classify it:

```
try{
//something
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        if($e instanceof PDOException){
              // handle PDOException
         }
}
```